# 500 error from ajax request (jQuery) to Code Igniter controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-2

Was wondering if anyone had encountered this problem.

I am calling a CI controller that runs a model (on the server) and takes longer (about 5 minutes) for a specific scenario.  The problem is that I am getting a 500 error after a long request but I do not get any errors when the request is shorter (about 1 and a half minutes).

Some things that I already checked:

- CI's 'csrf_protection' is OFF
- I've set a long timeout in my ajax call (900000)
- I've set max_execution_time in PHP to 900
- I've set Idle Time-Out in IIS to (20 minutes)

Here's my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"run/runScenario/" + saveOrUpdate + "/" + scenarioname + "/"  + units + "/" + stateid + "/" + climatestationid + "/" + soiltexture + "/" + 
                            moisturecontent + "/" + modsoilflag + "/" + slopelength + "/" +  slopeshape + "/" + slopesteepness + "/" + vegcommunity + "/" + 
                            basalcover + "/" + canopycover + "/" + rockcover + "/" + littercover + "/" + cryptogamscover,
    data: {scenarioDescription: scenariodescription},
    timeout:900000,
    statusCode: {
        500: function() {
          alert( "page not found" );
        }
      },
    success: function(runData){
            $('#progressBar').append('<p>Done running scenario.</p>');
            $('#progressBar').append('<p>Saving scenario...</p>');
            saveScenarioResultsTable();
            $('#progressBar').append('<p>Creating output table...</p>');
            printScenarioResultsTable(scenarioname);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                // stop timer
                var end = new Date().getTime();
                var execution_time = end - TIMER;
                runTimeMessage = "<br/><b>Ran scenario in " + (parseInt(execution_time) * 0.001) + " seconds.</b>";
                alert(runTimeMessage);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**  I created a test function (as part of my run controller) and set a *sleep(300)* inside the function.  I got the same 500 error.
But, when I change to *sleep(299)*, the function runs successfully.  Obviously, there is a 5 minute limit per request.
I have already changed the *max_execution_time* in php.ini.  Any other suggestions?

**UPDATE #2** I have found the solution to my problem. The problem was that because "safe_mode" was not enabled in my PHP settings, the PHP timeout was being overwritten in CodeIgniter.php (line 107). I am running CodeIgniter 2.1.4. I hope this helps someone else. :)

Comment: stackoverflow does not use bbcode markup. Please look at the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page

Comment: Interesting that if you hover over the code icon I see "<pre><code>" suggestions.

Comment: Manually type your service script to the browser with all required params to see if you really get error 500 - if yes - the problem in on service side not here in attached code

Comment: Another update.  I am still having this issue with my CI 2.1.3 installation.  I am not getting this behavior when running this under CI 1.7.2. 
I guess, the problem is probably with the CI 2.1.3 Session class.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea, but not a fixing of the code:

What if you will use two different ajax requests:

1. Request for processing and writing the result of processing in some buffer like file or sql record. This request may or may not return a random descriptor of future resource.
2. Request for getting results of processing by descriptor or just by availability of resources. This request have to be joined to the timer.

Timeline:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Step         Local            server          processing
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1. Request for processing >>> Server >>> Thread for processing
2. Descriptor of resource <<< Server >>> Descriptor of resource
3.                            Server <<< Result of processing
4. Request by descriptor  >>> Server
5.                 Result <<< Server >>> Deletion of file or record
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There:
1, 2 - Ajax #1, fires by demand.
4, 5 - Ajax #2, fires every 10sec.